# Find all auctions that maximize profit but are within budget

Tags: algorithm

I am not sure what an ideal algorithm would be to do the following.
I have a list of auctions. Each auction has a profit and a bid price. I am trying to bid on as many auctions as possible such that it maximises profit while minimizing cost as well as staying within a certain budget.

Example:

Budget: $1000

- Auction1: Profit: $500 cost: $100
- Auction2: Profit: $600 cost: $400
- Auction3: Profit: $1100 cost: $800
- Auction3: Profit: $700 cost: $500

I could get

- 1600$ profit with $900 cost. (A1 + A3) gives 77% profit
- 1800$ profit with $1000 cost. (A1 + A2 + A3) 80% profit

I would pick then the second one.

Comment: Knapsack problem.

Comment: Perfect :D I was looking exactly for that. Thank you